# Show dynamic data in JS

Tags: javascript, html, database, dynamic, dropdown

I need a functionality that when i click any item in my dropdown it should display corresponding names with the item. It is dynamic names and when i try it , it is not displaying the names but in dev mode i can see the names. it is displaying the names when i add like dummy data direct in html div but not dynamic.

when I use dummy names it is displaying properly but not dynamic names.

```js
const currentdate = new Date();
const anneeEncours = currentdate.getFullYear();
const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
const jourDeLaSemaine = currentdate.getDay();
const numjour = currentdate.getDate();

// Définir la date de début de l'année en cours
const debutAnnee = new Date(anneeEncours, 0, 1);

// Obtenir le jour de la semaine de la date de début de l'année en cours
const jourDebutAnnee = debutAnnee.getDay();

// Calculer le nombre de jours écoulés depuis le début de l'année en cours
const nbJoursEcoules = Math.floor((currentdate - debutAnnee) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

// Calculer le numéro de semaine
let numSemaine = Math.ceil((nbJoursEcoules + 1 - (jourDebutAnnee <= 4 ? jourDebutAnnee : jourDebutAnnee - 7)) / 7);

if (jourDeLaSemaine === 0) {
  numSemaine--;
}

//const joursSemaine = ['Dimanche', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Samedi'];
//const nomJourSemaine = joursSemaine[jourDeLaSemaine];

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC--sJFGdlLZ5wBK0gSpOXYxvhy_XGqEmA",
  authDomain: "new-chronos.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://new-chronos-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "new-chronos",
  storageBucket: "new-chronos.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "799425462266",
  appId: "1:799425462266:web:3c35d05a99077e97acee43"
};



const apiKey = 'AIzaSyClF7txE5QagR8BJaKGGxJk2YlJRR0wsRg';
const spreadsheetId = '1RtMPh3NLRf2ka37PVKzOdZhLWasv8Gf394AINa_devI';
const range = 'JOUR!A29:C300';


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const database = firebase.database();
const pathEmployees = `board/${numjour}/equipes`;
const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref(pathEmployees);
var cellsRef = database.ref('board/' + numjour + '/Cells');


const table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // Sélectionner le tableau avec l'ID "myTable"

var ligneIndex = 1; // Indice de la ligne spécifique (commence à 0 pour la première ligne)
var ligne = table.rows[ligneIndex];

// Parcourir les cellules de la ligne et ajouter des écouteurs
for (var i = 0; i < ligne.cells.length; i++) {
  var cell = ligne.cells[i];
  cell.id = `suz-${i}`;

  const addedLabelsDiv = document.createElement("div");
  addedLabelsDiv.className = "added-labels";
  addedLabelsDiv.id = `added-labels-${i}`;
  console.log(addedLabelsDiv.id);
  addedLabelsDiv.style.width = "100%";
  addedLabelsDiv.style.height = "80%";
  addedLabelsDiv.style.fontSize = "24px";

  //addedLabelsDiv.addEventListener("drop", drop);
  //addedLabelsDiv.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);

  cell.appendChild(addedLabelsDiv);
}




const rows = table.rows;

for (let i = 2; i < rows.length; i++) { // Commence à 2 pour sauter les 2 premieres lignues
  const cells = rows[i].cells;
  for (let j = 1; j < cells.length; j++) { // Commence à 1 pour sauter l'entête des lignes
    let cell = cells[j];
    cell.id = `${i}-${j}`;
    //console.log(cell.id); 
    //cell.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    //cell.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);
    const labelsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    labelsDiv.className = "labels";

    const label1 = document.createElement("span");
    label1.className = "label";
    label1.style.fontSize = "24px";
    label1.style.textAlign = "left";
    label1.id = `projet-${i}-${j}`;

    const label2 = document.createElement("span");
    label2.className = "label";
    label2.style.fontSize = "22px";
    label2.style.textAlign = "center";
    label2.style.color = "white";
    label2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    label2.id = `module-${i}-${j}`;

    labelsDiv.appendChild(label1);
    labelsDiv.appendChild(label2);

    const addedLabelsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    addedLabelsDiv.className = "added-labels";
    addedLabelsDiv.id = `added-labels-${i}-${j}`;
    console.log(addedLabelsDiv.id);
    addedLabelsDiv.style.width = "100%";
    addedLabelsDiv.style.height = "80%";
    addedLabelsDiv.style.fontSize = "24px";

    //addedLabelsDiv.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    //addedLabelsDiv.addEventListener("dragover", allowDrop);

    cell.appendChild(labelsDiv);
    cell.appendChild(addedLabelsDiv);
  }
}


let equipes = {};

async function readData() {
  try {

    const snapshotEmployees = await firebase.database().ref(pathEmployees).once("value");

    const snapshotpCMonteur = await firebase.database().ref(`board/${numjour}/Cells/personnesContainerMonteur`).once("value")
    const snapshotpCElectricien = await firebase.database().ref(`board/${numjour}/Cells/personnesContainerElectricien`).once("value")
    const snapshotpCSolier = await firebase.database().ref(`board/${numjour}/Cells/personnesContainerSolier`).once("value")
    const snapshotpCPlombier = await firebase.database().ref(`board/${numjour}/Cells/personnesContainerPlombier`).once("value")
    const snapshotpCPeintre = await firebase.database().ref(`board/${numjour}/Cells/personnesContainerPeintre`).once("value")



    if (snapshotEmployees.val() !== null && snapshotpCMonteur.val() !== null && snapshotpCElectricien.val() !== null && snapshotpCSolier.val() !== null && snapshotpCPlombier.val() !== null && snapshotpCPeintre.val() !== null) {
      console.log("frederic");




    } else {
      console.log("philippe");
      // Les nœuds n'existent pas, récupérer les données depuis la feuille de calcul
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${range}?key=${apiKey}`
      );

      const data = await response.json();
      //console.log(data);

      const employeesByMetier = {};

      data.values.forEach((row) => {
        const nom = row[0]; // Colonne du nom de l'employé
        const metier = row[1]; // Colonne du métier/qualification de l'employé
        const contrat = row[2];

        const employee = {
          name: nom,
          job: metier,
          int: contrat,
        };

        if (!employeesByMetier.hasOwnProperty(metier)) {
          employeesByMetier[metier] = [];
        }

        employeesByMetier[metier].push(employee);
      });

      const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref(pathEmployees);

      for (const metier in employeesByMetier) {
        if (employeesByMetier.hasOwnProperty(metier)) {
          const equipe = employeesByMetier[metier];
          firebaseRef.child(metier).set(equipe);

          // Trouver ou créer le "personnesContainer" pour ce métier
          let container5 = document.getElementById(`personnesContainer${metier}`);
          if (container5) {
            container5 = document.createElement('div');
            container5.id = `personnesContainer${metier}`;
            container5.style.display = "none";

            document.body.appendChild(container5); // Changez 'document.body' en fonction de l'endroit où vous voulez ajouter le conteneur
          }

          // Vider le contenu du "personnesContainer" correspondant
          container5.innerHTML = '';

          // Parcourir l'équipe et créer une div pour chaque personne
          for (const personne of equipe) {
            const personneDiv = document.createElement('div');
            personneDiv.textContent = `${personne.name}`; // Ajoutez les autres propriétés
            personneDiv.fontSize = "24px";
            container5.appendChild(personneDiv);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur lors de la lecture du tableur ou lors de sauvegarde dans Firebase :", error);
  }
}

readData();
const metierDropdown = document.getElementById('metier');

// Get the containers for each type of person
const personnesContainers = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="personnesContainer"]');

// Function to show the container based on the selected value
function showContainer() {
  const selectedValue = metierDropdown.value;
  personnesContainers.forEach(container => {
    container.style.display = 'none';
  });
  if (selectedValue) {
    document.getElementById(`personnesContainer${selectedValue}`).style.display = 'block';
  }
}

// Add event listener to the dropdown change event
metierDropdown.addEventListener('change', showContainer);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>The Board</h2>

    <button style=" border-radius: 5px;" id="toggleButton">Jour</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>



    <select id="metier">
      <option value="">Choisir un métier</option>
      <option value="Monteur">Monteur</option>
      <option value="Electricien">Electricien</option>
      <option value="Solier">Solier</option>
      <option value="Peintre">Peintre</option>
      <option value="Plombier">Plombier</option>
    </select>

    <div id="personnesContainerElectricien">huuu</div>
    <div id="personnesContainerMonteur"></div>
    <div id="personnesContainerSolier"></div>
    <div id="personnesContainerPeintre"></div>
    <div id="personnesContainerPlombier"></div>




  </div>
</div>

<div id="form-container" style="display: none;">
  <form id="cell-form">
    <label id="selected-cell-label" style="font-size: 30px;"></label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="project-number">Numéro de projet:</label>
    <input type="text" id="project-number" name="project-number" style="font-size: 24px;"><br><br>
    <label for="module-number">Numéro de module:</label>
    <input type="text" id="module-number" name="module-number" style="font-size: 24px;"><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="priority" name="priority">
    <label for="priority">Priorité</label><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="completed" name="completed">
    <label for="completed">Achevé</label><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="cancel-form" value="Annuler" style="font-size: 24px;">
    <input type="button" id="submit-form" value="Soumettre" style="font-size: 24px;">
  </form>
</div>


<div id="overlay"></div>



<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it so it is a [mcve] - there is far too much code node